# Dart sort / compare nullable datetime

Tags: datetime, dart

I'm trying to compare list of music with releaseDate. But I can retrieve music without releaseDate and when I want to sort them, I got an error.

How can I sort / compare nullable datetime and put null releaseDate to the end?

```
_followedMusic.sort((a, b) {
  if (a.releaseDate != null && b.releaseDate != null)
    return a.releaseDate.compareTo(b.releaseDate);
  else
    // return ??
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for `compareTo`:

> Returns a value like a Comparator when comparing this to other. That is, it returns a negative integer if this is ordered before other, a positive integer if this is ordered after other, and zero if this and other are ordered together.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-core/Comparable/compareTo.html

So your `compareTo` should just result in returning the values `-1`, `0` or `1` according to if the compared object should be before, the same position or after the current object.

So in your case if you want your `null` entries to be at the start of the sorted list, you can do something like this:

```
void main() {
  final list = ['b', null, 'c', 'a', null];

  list.sort((s1, s2) {
    if (s1 == null && s2 == null) {
      return 0;
    } else if (s1 == null) {
      return -1;
    } else if (s2 == null) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
  });

  print(list); // [null, null, a, b, c]
}
```

Or if you want the `null` at the end:

```
void main() {
  final list = ['b', null, 'c', 'a', null];

  list.sort((s1, s2) {
    if (s1 == null && s2 == null) {
      return 0;
    } else if (s1 == null) {
      return 1;
    } else if (s2 == null) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
  });

  print(list); // [a, b, c, null, null]
}
```

Or, as @lrn suggests, make the last example in a more short and efficient way (but maybe not as readable :) ):

```
void main() {
  final list = ['b', null, 'c', 'a', null];

  list.sort((s1, s2) => s1 == null
      ? s2 == null
          ? 0
          : 1
      : s2 == null
          ? -1
          : s1.compareTo(s2));

  print(list); // [a, b, c, null, null]
}
```

Comment: Ah ok! Really thank you. I now understand how to use "1", "0" and "-1"!

Comment: You should return zero if both values are `null`, otherwise you risk ... well, probably not a lot, but some particularly naive sorting implementations have been known to loop forever with an inconsistent compare function. So `=> s1 == null ? s2 == null ? 0 : 1 : s2 == null ? -1 : s1.compareTo(s2)`.

Comment: @lrn Oh yes. I forgot that! Thanks for mentioning it. :)

Answer (score 1):

what about `_followdMusic.map((date) => return date ?? 1900.01.01).toList().sort(...)`

the date is pseudo code, not sure how to write it. This way you put all unknown dates at one of the ends of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @julemand101 also can be used with the extension function.

```
extension DateEx on DateTime? {
  int compareToWithNull(DateTime? date2) {
    if (this == null && date2 == null) {
      return 0;
    } else if (this == null) {
      return -1;
    } else if (date2 == null) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return this!.compareTo(date2);
    }
  }
}
```